# Risks of using SQL trigger to run an exe

Tags: sql, exec, exe

What are the risks of running an exe on an sql trigger? This is a closed server, intranet only, with limited user access to the server where the script runs from and the SQL server connection.

I store outgoing emails temporarily in a table in my database system. These are then sent out via a trigger that runs and exe. The exe simply pulls the to, from, subject, cc, and body from the DB and send the email via CDO.

I have to use an outside method of sending emails instead of simply sending from code-behind in order to avoid slwodown on the website. I asked regarding this specific issue in another post, but asking about exec risks seemed like a seperate issue. Direct any alternatives to the related post.

Related post [Email from web without tying up webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180991/email-from-web-without-tying-up-webpage)

Comment: Well, that would of course depend a whole lot on what the exe does when triggered.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to run an executable from within a trigger?

Comment: I've added details on the exe and why I am using this method above.

Comment: I second @SchmitzIT. Are you able to provide context as to what actions the exe does for you? Perhaps there's an alternative solution outside of SQL Triggers entirely.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? Can't you use database mail?

Comment: @martinsmith What is database mail?

Comment: Provides asynchronous mail sending capabilities in SQL Server. [Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @martinsmith I've had trouble using simply SMTP message sending due to firewall issues beyond my control level. CDO allows for sending, but simple SMTP is blocked, and from that link Database Mail uses simple SMTP.

Comment: What about using CLR code instead? That's at least managed. I would strongly recommend you to reconsider using an executable from within a trigger. It has trouble spelled all over it.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Why would you strongly recommend reconsidering? I'm looking for the risks involved. Please add an answer with those risks. Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should **NEVER** do any lengthy processing in a trigger - NEVER EVER. A trigger fires uncontrollably, you cannot control when and how often it gets triggered. You should limit yourself to the **absolute minimum** in a trigger - make an entry into an audit or command table - nothing more. Do not ever do any lengthy processing! That'll totally kill your system performance!

Comment: @marc_s cannot control when and how? I thought setting a trigger on insert controlled the exec to run on each record insert. Is this not true? Also, how does it kill system performance? I want to fully understand the risks. Adding as an answer might be a better place for discussion.

Comment: Watch [Brent Ozar's Top 10 Developer Mistakes That Don't Scale](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/the-top-10-developer-mistakes-that-wont-scale/) - he talks about triggers in depth

Comment: @steventnorris: yes, an INSERT trigger runs on any INSERT - but it's not like you can actually **call** the trigger at given times (or **not call it**) - it will fire every time an INSERT happens - you cannot control this (other than not inserting.....)

Comment: @marc_s that's what I want to happen. I'm looking to send an email every time a record is inserted.

Comment: @steventnorris: and I would argue - **don't**! At least **don't do it directly in the trigger**. The trigger should only put an entry into a *send an e-mail for this new row* command table - a second, async process (e.g. scheduled to run every 10 minutes or so) would then read that table and do the actual sending of the e-mails.

Comment: @marc_s I've heard that before as well. It's actually a second option I was looking into. I may end up going that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a closed server and the .exe is known, I don't see that there would be much risk if any.  The only risk I could see would be if someone changed your exe for something else that would then be triggered, but that seems unlikely given the scenario you described.

We had a similar situation several years ago where we had a vendor whose product was updated via a control program.  We had a trigger that hit the control program each time a user was added to the sql database, and the control program would then signal its service to add the user there as well.  Never had a real problem with it.